# iTunesConnect - Bundle ID Suffix

Tags: app-store-connect

I know this issue seems to be asked before, but I couldn't find a clear answer either way. Thought it's a good idea to start a clean thread:

I'm in the process of trying to submit my first app on iTunesConnect, and encounters a situation where I need to input the **Bundle ID Suffix** in addition to the **Bundle ID**. I know that the Bundle ID is the 10 digit alphanumeric thing. The Bundle suffix seems to be something to do with "com.companyName.appName", and needs to be the same as what's in the XCode info.plist. When I look at my XCode **info.plist** I see a few related thing:

- **Bundle display name:**  ${PRODUCT_NAME}
- **Bundle identifier:** companyName.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
- **Bundle name:** ${PRODUCT_NAME}

So my questions are:

1. Is the Bundle ID Suffix only required when the App ID is of "**wild card**" type?
2. What should I put in my bundle ID? is it **com.companyName.appName**, **companyName.appName**, or simply **appName**?
3. It seems it's commonly advised to overwrite the ${PRODUCT_NAME} and ${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}. From appearance it seems some type of macro to grab the default app name. But should I simply overwrite both of them as appName? What is the difference between **${PRODUCT_NAME}**  and **${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}**?

Much thanks for viewing!

Answer (score 6):

1: **wild card** is the opposite of the type where You have to use **Bundle ID Suffixes**, so don't use wild cards
2: You should put **com.companyName.appName**
3: from my point of view, the difference between these two is completely irrelevant because they represent the same thing, You should overwrite them both with **appName**
:)

Comment: Thanks! This really helps me. One quick question: if my company domain name extension is .gov should my bundleid be gov.companyname.appname?

Comment: Yes, I think You should. I have seen others using the same principle for other domain extensions.  
Glad I could help!

Comment: Helped me too. Thanks